# plugin admin subpage title and links in menu not highlited at current page

Tags: links, title, add-submenu-page

In my custom plugin subapges i want to echo their titles specifed in add_submenu_page() but i don't know how do that.

This is part of code of my plugin which display links in left-side menu:

```
add_menu_page('Title', 'Title', 'manage_options', 'my-parent', 'my_page', 'dashicons-clipboard');
add_submenu_page( 'my-parent', 'Main title', 'Main title', 'manage_options', 'my_page');
add_submenu_page( 'my-parent', 'Subpage title', 'Subpage title', 'manage_options', 'my_subpage', 'subpage-handle');
```

What i must echo of each subpage between `<?php ... ?>` to display titles specifed above?

And why links from left-side menu are not higlithed when im at current subpage? I got other plugins and when i go to the his subpage links are higlited in menu.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `add_submenu_page()` you have to specify a callback function at the end. Like you did it in the 2nd submenu page. You have to add this function to your code!

Example:

```
add_submenu_page( 'my-parent', 'Subpage title', 'Subpage title', 'manage_options', 'my_subpage', 'subpage-handle');

function subpage-handle()
{
    echo '<h1>Subpage title</h1>';
}
```

In this function you can echo whatever you want. I also reproduced your highlight behavior. It seems everything works fine.

Full example:

```
function add_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Title', 'Title', 'manage_options', 'my-parent', 'my_page', 'dashicons-clipboard');
    add_submenu_page( 'my-parent', 'Main title', 'Main title', 'manage_options', 'my-subpage', 'my_1st_subpage');
    add_submenu_page( 'my-parent', 'Subpage title', 'Subpage title', 'manage_options', 'my-subpage-2', 'my_2nd_subpage');
}

function my_page()
{
    echo '<h1>Title</h1>';
}

function my_1st_subpage()
{
    echo '<h1>Main title</h1>';
}

function my_2nd_subpage()
{
    echo '<h1>Subpage title</h1>';
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu');
```